# How to compare comma delimited field to find number of occurrences

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a related recipes query. It currently returns rows that have the ids for the ingredients

```
SELECT recipeid,GROUP_CONCAT(ingredientid ORDER BY ingredientid ASC) as 'ingredientids' FROM `recipeingredients` GROUP BY recipeid

recipeid  ingredientids
1         122,288,364,450,560...
2         122,290,321,450,602...
.
.
```

I want to find all recipes from the above query that match 60% of the ingredientids OR 6 or more of a given value (ex 122,290,350)

Can this be done in a single query?

Comment: That does not look good - is it possible to fix the database design?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT recipeid,
GROUP_CONCAT(ingredientid ORDER BY ingredientid ASC) as 'ingredientids' 
FROM `recipeingredients` 
GROUP BY recipeid
HAVING SUM(ingredientid IN (122, 290, 350)) >= FLOOR(COUNT(*) * 0.6)
OR SUM(ingredientid IN (122, 290, 350)) >= 6
```

This `ingredientid IN (122, 290, 350)` in the `SUM()` function is a boolean expression which returns 1 for true and 0 for false.